# Laravel : get user id in the api controller using Passport

Tags: laravel, laravel-passport

We are trying to retrieve the authentified user id on the api controller:

```
$user = auth('api')->id();
return FormulaireResource::collection(Formulaire::where('user_id', $user)->paginate(15));
```

the problem come from `$user` who's always NULL

here is the API.php:

```
Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});
```

We are generating users with token but not able to use them.

thanks for the feedback

Comment: Shouldn't that be `$user = auth('api')->user()->id;`?

Comment: I already tried, i got: `trying to get property 'id' of non-object`

Comment: Then if `user()` returns null, your user is not logged in with the 'api' guard.

Comment: Post as well the `config/auth.php` file